# Sum of independent diagonal in a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, diagonal

I'm currently studying for an exam and I'm trying to deal with dynamical matrix. I've come across a problem regarding calculating the sum of every diagonal of a matrix whose values and size are chosen by the user.
The intent of my program is to print, thanks to a function, whose parameters are the matrix and its size, the value of every diagonal sum. I'll show you the code and describe it in depth.

```
----------------
| 52 | 35 | 5  |  Example of matrix.
----------------  Imagine the first diagonal to be the one which goes right-to-left
| 2  | 71 | 1  |  and only consists in the number "47".
----------------  The second diagonal would be the one which goes right-to-left and
| 3  | 60 | 25 |  consists in the number "15" and "79".
----------------  So to get the sum of the second diagonal it would be:
| 79 | 55 | 98 |     
----------------  sum = m[n_rows - 1][diag - 2] + m[n_rows - 2][diag - 1]
| 47 | 15 | 66 | 
----------------  When diag > columns, in order to avoid error regarding matrix size,
                  I should lower the quantity "n_rows - 1" by the quantity "diag - n_columns".
```

This is what I thought to do, according to my description:

```
void diag_matrix(int** m, int righe, int colonne){//righe = rows, colonne = columns. 
//M is the matrix.

// diag is the number of the diagonal I'm considering.
    for(int diag = 1; diag < (righe + colonne); diag++){ 

        int sum = 0;// the sum
        int i = 0;// the counter of the cicle
        int l = 0;// this is the value to riallign the row in case diag > column
        int temp = diag;//I use this variable not to modify the value of diag.

        // What I want is: when the column-index/row-index of the matrix reaches 0, the cicle will interrupt (after final iteration);
        while(righe - i - l - 1 > 0 || diag - 1 - i > 0){

            if (diag > colonne){//this condition changes l-value only if diag value is greater than column. Explanation outside the code
                l = diag - colonne;//this is the value to subtract to row-index
                temp = colonne;//this position is necessary to set column-index to its maxium.
            }

            sum = sum + m[righe - 1 - l - i][temp -1 - i];//pretty clear I think.
            i++;//the i is incremented by one.

        }// end of while-statement

        cout << "Somma Diagonale " << diag << " = " << sum << ".\n";

    }// end of for-statement

}//end of function declaration
```

Obviously it does not work, but I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify... you want to start at bottom right corner and the work towards the top, right ?

Comment: Are you stuck with that representation of the arrays and that function signature, or can you use a different data structure if you want?

Comment: In this instance modular arithmetic is extremely useful.  Knowing your starting position in the matrix, you can modulo add/subtract from both i,j, depending on which of the four diagonal directions you're heading in, until you detect a wrap around of either i or j.

Comment: @Davislor I'm open to use a different data structure if it would result in a more efficient data management. However, my main intent is to understand the error in my code.

Comment: @CJPN I've not fully understand your idea. I've tried to subtract units to row/column-index but I've been receiving the same error (which is a crash). Can you explain what is your idea? Sorry.

Comment: Google "modular mathematics".  It would appear that it is the destination your exam study is pointing you towards.  We're not here to perform your homework/study on your behalf. :)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Your solution works! But can you explainme why mine failed where yours succeded?

Comment: A general principle here is: always, *always*, ***always*** check your array accesses for buffer overruns and underruns.

Comment: @CJPN I don’t give complete answers to problems that sound like homework (I don’t think it’s in anyone’s interest), but in this case, I felt I had some sample code that was worth studying.

Comment: @CJPN First of all, it was not a homework; I didn't want you to do the exercise on my behalf. Moreover, this is just a part of a major program I'm developing just to exercise. I just wanted to know where I was making an error. Anyway, thanks for the tip, but it was not what I was asking for, neither the subject I have to study for my exam.

Comment: @KingPowa Right, I gave a complete answer because you said it wasn’t homework. Unfortunately, the extra boilerplate to make it a full program that compiles and runs seems to have buried the one function that does fully address the question, albeit in a different way. I should probably have separated that out. Sorry you didn’t find my answer more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code finding the starting position of each diagonal and then stepping through the matrix as long as the coordinates stay inside the matrix.
Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void diag_matrix(int** m, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int diag = 1; diag < rows + cols; diag++)
    {
        int x, y;
        if (diag < rows)
        {
            y = rows - diag;
            x = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            y = 0;
            x = diag - rows;
        }
        int sum = 0;
        cout << "Summing diagonal #" << diag << ":";
        while ((x < cols) && (y < rows))
        {
            sum += m[y][x];
            cout << " " << m[y][x];
            x++;
            y++;
        }
        cout << " result: " << sum << "." << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int rows = 5, cols = 3;
    int **m = new int*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        m[i] = new int[cols];
    m[0][0] = 52; m[0][1] = 35; m[0][2] =  5;
    m[1][0] =  2; m[1][1] = 71; m[1][2] =  1;
    m[2][0] =  3; m[2][1] = 60; m[2][2] = 25;
    m[3][0] = 79; m[3][1] = 55; m[3][2] = 98;
    m[4][0] = 47; m[4][1] = 15; m[4][2] = 66;
    diag_matrix(m, rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        delete[] m[i];
    delete[] m;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does that enable adding up an arbitrary number of adjacent diagonal rows?

Comment: @KingPowa I think you may need sum+=m[y][x] for your matrix.

Comment: @CJPN It calculates the sum of each "mainish" diagonal, one by one (so the ones running in a top-left-bottom-right direction), starting with the single-element diagonal in the bottom left corner and ending with the other single-element diagonal in the top right corner. TBH I am not sure if that is what you have asked.

Comment: This is exactly what I've asked, but I get wrong values and sometimes crash when using your code (based on the arbitrary size of the matrix);

Comment: @tevemadar I've just realized that the condition in your while should be "swapped". Now the code works, but it seems like that the first and last 2 diagonals can't be calculated properly.  They are always equal to 0.

Comment: @KingPowa this was just typed on a phone, later today I will put together a complete example with the matrix you have in the question.

Comment: @Bob__ thanks for fixing the cols-columns thing. However I am not sure why you altered the bracket-conventions, it was a legal one and it also matched the one used in the question.

Comment: Ops... Sorry for that, it's a matter of habit.

Answer (score 2):

(There used to be a paragraph here, but on a second look, you didn’t make the mistake it was talking about.)

Since you didn’t post to Code Reviews, here’s a solution instead of a detailed code review.  (If you want to make the original approach work, I’d suggest single-stepping through it in a debugger and checking where your variables first get the wrong value.)  It’s got a lot of boilerplate to make it compile and run, but the part you’ll be most interested in is `diag_sums()` and its comments.

One idea here is to use OOP to automatically check the bounds of your array accesses.  The latter is very important for catching off-by-one errors and the like.  You can turn it off in production if you want, but you really don’t want to silence warnings when your program has a buffer overrun.  Other optimizations here include locality of access for the data, and strength reduction on the operations: rather than check on each iteration whether we’ve hit the right edge and the bottom edge, we can simply calculate the length of each diagonal in advance.

Since the definition of diagonal number *k* of matrix `a` with *M* rows is equivalent to: all elements `a[i][j]` such that such that *M* - *k* = *i* - *j*, the algorithm ensures correctness by maintaining the invariant, which holds whenever we add 1 to both *i* and *j*, starting when either *i* or *j* is 0, and stopping whenever *i* = *M* or *j* = *N*, that is, traversing each step of the diagonal from the left or top edge to the right or bottom edge, whichever comes first.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

template <typename T>
  class matrix {
    public:
      matrix( const ptrdiff_t rows,
              const ptrdiff_t cols,
              std::vector<T>&& elems )
        : rows_(rows), cols_(cols), elems_(elems)
      {
        assert( rows_ > 0 );
        assert( cols_ > 0 );
        assert( elems_.size() == static_cast<size_t>(rows_*cols_) );
      }

      matrix( const ptrdiff_t rows,
              const ptrdiff_t cols,
              const std::vector<T>& elems )
        : matrix( rows, cols, std::move(std::vector<T>(elems)) )
      {}

      matrix( const matrix<T>& ) = default;
      matrix( matrix<T>&& ) = default;
      matrix& operator= ( const matrix<T>& ) = default;
      matrix& operator= ( matrix<T>&& ) = default;

      T& operator() ( const ptrdiff_t m, const ptrdiff_t n )
      {
        assert( m >= 0 && m < rows_ );
        assert( n >= 0 && n < cols_ );
        return elems_[static_cast<size_t>(m*cols_ + n)];
      }

      const T& operator() ( const ptrdiff_t m, const ptrdiff_t n ) const
      {
       /* Because this call does not modify any data, and the only reason the
        * member function above cannot be const is that it returns a non-const
        * reference to an element of elems, casting away the const qualifier
        * internally and then returning a const reference is a safe way to
        * re-use the code.
        */
        matrix<T>& nonconst = *const_cast<matrix<T>*>(this);
        return nonconst(m,n);
      }

      ptrdiff_t rows() const { return rows_; }
      ptrdiff_t cols() const { return cols_; }

    private:
      ptrdiff_t rows_;
      ptrdiff_t cols_;
      std::vector<T> elems_;
  };

template<typename T>
  std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& out, const matrix<T>& x )
  /* Boilerplate to print a matrix. */
  {
    const ptrdiff_t m = x.rows(), n = x.cols();

    for ( ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < m; ++i ) {
      out << x(i,0);
      for ( ptrdiff_t j = 1; j < n; ++j )
        out << ' ' << x(i,j);

      out << '\n';
    } // end for

    return out;
  }

using elem_t = int;

std::vector<elem_t> diag_sums( const matrix<elem_t>& a )
/* Return a vector of all the diagonal sums of a.
 *
 * The first diagonal sum is a(rows-1,0)
 * The second is a(rows-2,0) + a(rows-1,1)
 * The third is a(rows-3,0) + a(rows-2,1) + a(rows-1,2)
 * And so on.  I.e., the kth diagonal is the sum of all elements a(i,j) such
 * that i - j == rows - k.
 *
 * If a is a M×N matrix, there are M diagonals starting in column zero, and
 * N-1 diagonals (excluding the one containing a(0,0) so we don't count it
 * twice) starting in row 0.  We process them bottom to top, then left to
 * right.
 *
 * The number of elements in a diagonal starting at a(i,0) is min{M-i, N}.  The
 * number of elements in a diagonal starting at a(0,j) is min{M, N-j}.  This is
 * because a diagonal stops at either the bottom edge or the left edge of a.
 */
{
  const ptrdiff_t m = a.rows(), n = a.cols();
  std::vector<elem_t> result;
  result.reserve( static_cast<size_t>(m + n - 1) );

  for ( ptrdiff_t i = m-1; i > 0; --i ) {
    elem_t sum = 0;

    const ptrdiff_t nk = (m-i) < n ? (m-i) : n;
    for ( ptrdiff_t k = 0; k < nk; ++k )
      sum += a(i+k, k);

    result.emplace_back(sum);
  } // end for i

  for ( ptrdiff_t j = 0; j < n; ++j ) {
    elem_t sum = 0;

    const ptrdiff_t nk = m < (n-j) ? m : (n-j);
    for ( ptrdiff_t k = 0; k < nk; ++k )
      sum += a(k, j+k);

    result.emplace_back(sum);
  } // end for j

  return result;
}

matrix<elem_t> read_input_matrix( const int row, const int column )
/* Reads in row*column consecutive elements from cin and packs them into a
 * matrix<elem_t>.
 */
{
  assert(row > 0);
  assert(column > 0);

  const ptrdiff_t nelements = row*column;
  assert(nelements > 0); // Check for overflow.

  std::vector<elem_t> result;
  result.reserve(static_cast<size_t>(nelements));

  for ( ptrdiff_t i = nelements; i > 0; --i ) {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    assert(cin.good());
    result.push_back(x);
  }

  return matrix<elem_t>( row,
                         column,
                         std::move(result) );
}

template<typename T>
  bool print_sequence( const T& container )
  /* Prints the contents of a container in the format
   * "{47, 94, 124, 160, 148, 36, 5}".
   */
  {
    cout << "{";

    if ( container.begin() != container.end() )
      cout << *container.begin();

    for ( auto it = container.begin() + 1; it < container.end(); ++it )
      cout << ", " << *it;

    cout << "}\n";

    return cout.good();
  }

/* A simple test driver that reads in the number of rows, the number of
 * columns, and then row*columns int values, from standard input.  It
 * then passes the result to diag_matrix(), E.g.:
 *
 * 5 3
 * 52 35  5
 *  2 71  1
 *  3 60 25
 * 79 55 98
 * 47 15 66
 */
int main()
{
  int rows, columns;
  cin >> rows;
  cin >> columns;

  assert(cin.good());

  const matrix<elem_t> input_matrix = read_input_matrix( rows, columns );
  // cout << input_matrix; // Instrumentation.
  const std::vector<elem_t> sums = diag_sums(input_matrix);

  print_sequence(sums);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You could also just do `print_sequence(diag_sums(read_input_matrix( rows, columns )))`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and patience. I'm new to this forum and probably I should've posted in the section you've pointed out. Anyway your solution deals with classes, which is a subject that is not part of my exam. I should've pointed out. However, I will try the code and study it in order to undestand the structure, which doesn't seem hard to fully understand. Again, thank you for your patience and sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Why use template? Aren't it overkill?

Comment: @Sugar Probably!

Comment: @KingPowa You asked a good question. If it helps, you can pretty much ignore the part of the solution that uses templates. Maybe I should've split it up into modules, to put more emphasis on the part that was relevant to your question. Basically, the class is a really fancy way of being able to write `a(i,j)` instead of `a[i][j]. Although I wrote it that way because I think it has advantages, especially in catching bugs.

Comment: For example, when I first wrote `diag_sums()`, I originally typed `m-1` for `m-i` in one of the two places. (Which maybe means I should’ve written `min()` instead of repeating myself.) This raised an assertion immediately and reproducibly, which I could trap in the debugger and backtrace. Similarly when I switched `rows` and `cols` at one point. Maybe there’s some C++ coder who doesn’t shoot himself in the foot that way and doesn’t need to code defensively, but not I.